# MySQL query must return results (sorted by proximity to user current location) just in a radius of 5 km

Tags: mysql, sql, location, proximity, radius

I've created a mySql query that returns all results sorted by proximity to user current location. Here it's:

```
SELECT ID FROM myTable ORDER BY (POW((longitude-40.23120),2) + POW((latitude-23.12302),2)) LIMIT 0,10
```

I state that the numerical values ​​are respectively the longitude and latitude of the current user.
It works properly, but I need to add a constraint to the query: I want the query returns the results in a radius of 5 km and it doesn't return results outside that radius.

Comment: You can get the distance calculation easily enough by searching on the web.  You *could* make the problem simpler by changing the requirement from a circle to a box, so you can compare latitude and longitude separately.